# Alteration Color Change for Listbox

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a listbox and I want to change the color of every other row.  I have tested the following code, but the colors are not changing. Am I missing something?

```
<ListBox Height="250" BorderThickness="0" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Results}" AlternationCount="2">
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                                <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                                <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" FontFamily="Sagoe UI" FontSize="14" Text="{Binding FirstName, StringFormat='User: {0}'}" Padding="2"  />
                            <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" FontFamily="Sagoe UI" FontSize="14" Text="{Binding Company, StringFormat='Company: {0}'}" Padding="2" /> 
                            <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" FontFamily="Sagoe UI" FontSize="14" Text="{Binding Dept, StringFormat='Department: {0}'}" Padding="2" >                                
                            </TextBlock>
                        </Grid>                        
                    </DataTemplate>
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

Here is my style and the closing tags for resoruces and dictionary

```
        <Style  TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="ItemsControl.AlternationIndex" Value="0">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#19f39611"></Setter>
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="ItemsControl.AlternationIndex" Value="1">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#19000000"></Setter>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

Comment: Just tested out your code. Works for me.

Comment: Thanks, I thought it was right, Ill keep digging thanks!

Comment: Thanks again cvraman! I'm going to go slap myself!!

Comment: Your pasted code worked with normal listbox as well. You can mark your solution as answer :)

Comment: Yea Tried Marking it as answer, have to wait 2 days to use my own answer!  Thanks Again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow `Forgot` I was using `RadListBox`, so the answer is change the opening and closing `Control Tags` To

```
 <telerik:RadListBox></telerik:RadListBox>
```

Then

```
     <Style  TargetType="{x:Type telerik:RadListBoxItem}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="ItemsControl.AlternationIndex" Value="0">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#19f39611"></Setter>
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="ItemsControl.AlternationIndex" Value="1">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#19000000"></Setter>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</UserControl.Resources>
```